# Next-Sass not compiling?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, sass, next.js

I have followed everything from nextjs's examples and i cant find anything wrong...

[Error given by nextjs dev server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T85GT.png)

[image]

**Above - FIXED**

**/ Current Issue /**

Its like next-sass isnt being used when it goes through a .scss file, im not sure whats happening. If i remove the imports from my SCSS file, the same error is thrown for everything else in the file.

The page is being rendered now, but none of the SCSS is being deployed and my index.TSX is now throwing

> 'boot' is declared but its value is never read.ts(6133)

Next.config.js

```
const withTypescript = require("@zeit/next-typescript");
const withSass = require("@zeit/next-sass");

module.exports = withTypescript(), withSass();
```

index.tsx

```
import * as React from "react";
import * as ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import _ from "lodash";

import boot from "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss"
import the from "../styles/theme_common.scss";
import MasterLayout from "../components/masterLayout.container";
```

If anyone could help me solve this, this has halted development :(

Comment: try `import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss"`

Comment: also this is the first time that I see this way of exporting modules. Where have you seen it? I would like to know

Comment: From https://github.com/zeit/next-plugins/tree/master/packages/next-sass#with-css-modules @evgenifotia.
Oh and i tried importing it the other way but that just puts me back to the original issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is how you are exporting multiple modules try this

```
const withTypescript = require("@zeit/next-typescript");
const withSass = require('@zeit/next-sass')
module.exports = withTypescript(withSass({
    cssModules: true
}))
```

and do `import "../styles/theme_common.scss";` the same for the rest

Answer (score 0):

The documentation seems to show a slightly different syntax for adding SASS Support with CSS.

https://github.com/zeit/next-plugins/tree/master/packages/next-sass#with-css-modules

```
// next.config.js
const withSass = require('@zeit/next-sass')
module.exports = withSass({
    cssModules: true
})
```

Comment: I already tried this but for some reason its working now? I hadnt even changed anything... How strange...

Comment: @Stryxus before you haven't restarted the server

Comment: I rebooted the server before but now iv ran into another issue. None of the SCSS is still being compiled and the TSX file has an error on the import saying it cant find a module.

Comment: @Stryxus,  out of interest, is css support mandatory?  From what you've supplied, I don't see any css files being loaded.

Comment: Oh yes, that has already been removed, it was testing for importing bootstrap by URL. Ill update that now.